# Translate java encrypting to php

Tags: java, php, encryption

I'm trying to make a hash in php but I cant get the correct hash.

The java code is:

```
if (sPassword == null || sPassword.equals("")) {
        return "empty:";
    } else {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(sPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] res = md.digest();
            return "sha1:" + StringUtils.byte2hex(res);



        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return "plain:" + sPassword;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return "plain:" + sPassword;
        }
    }
```

Can somebody translate this to php?

For example if I put in Java the following pass: `123456789`, The hash is: `sha1:625D7360E198F528978A4D061F3420923AF867C5`.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP has an `sha1()` function, your code should be something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($sPassword == null || $sPassword == "")
    {
        return "empty:";
    }
    else
    {
        if (!function_exists("sha1"))
        {
            return "plain:" . $sPassword;
        }
        else
        {
            return "sha1:" . strtoupper(sha1($sPassword));
        }
    }
?>
```

The `strtoupper()` is needed to make the hash uppercase as the `sha1()` returns it in lowercase. I believe the `function_exists("sha1")` will always return false as the `sha1()` is a built-in function. But maybe with some specific build options you can get rid of it.

Just a note: `sha1()` **will give you** a hash for empty passwords.

Comment: Thanks, this code gives me sha1 hash: f7c3bc1d808e04732adf679965ccc34ca7ae3441 for input 123456789.And i need: sha1:625D7360E198F528978A4D061F3420923AF867C5.

Comment: Are you sure that's the hash for "123456789"? I've checked the hash on a site with an sha1 hash database and it says the input is ".adgjmptw" (which is correct for the PHP version). Could you try another input and share the results here?

Comment: It is interesting that the characters of ".adgjmptw" are three steps away from each other in the ASCII table (excluding the "."), it seems that the `.getBytes("UTF-8")` is doing some unexpected things to the input string.

Answer (score 0):

simply try this:

```
   <?PHP
        $sPassword  =   "enter-password-here";
        if(!empty($sPassword)) {
            return sprintf("sha1 hash: %s", sha1($sPassword));
        } else {
            return "empty";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: since we are using "return" I believe this code is part of a user defined `function()`

Comment: Thanks, this code gives me sha1 hash: f7c3bc1d808e04732adf679965ccc34ca7ae3441 for input 123456789.And i need: sha1:625D7360E198F528978A4D061F3420923AF867C5.